# Cartesian product of only one column in Pyspark?

Tags: dataset, pyspark, rdd, cartesian

As specified in the question i want to do the cartesian with just of one column of rdd. Example:

```
rdd1:
id1  A
id2  B
id3  C
```

My output should be:

```
id1 A A
id1 A B
id1 A C
id2 B A
id2 B B
id2 B C
id3 C A
id3 C B
id3 C C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this creating a new RDD with only the second column, `rdd2=rdd.map(lambda l: l[1])`. Then do the `cartesian` of these two RDDs:

`rdd.cartesian(rdd2).map(lambda v: (v[0][0],v[0][1],v[1]))`

The `map` is there because `cartesian` will return rows like `((id1,A),A)`, and the `map`converts that to `(id1,A,A)`